# Pandas read dataframe with numpy array column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, dataframe

I have a function that is doing some data processing on a pandas dataframe. One of the columns in the dataframe is a numpy array. I save the dataframe to a csv then when I try to read it, it reads the array as a string. I am trying to figure out how to get past this.

After processing the data I write my dataframe as a csv:

```
df.to_csv('./dataframe')
```

In another notebook I will read this dataframe from memory:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./dataframe')
```

I then try to extract the column with the numpy array and combine them all into one large 2D array:

```
npArray = np.zeros((df.shape[0], 4000)) #each numpy array 
                                          #in the dataframe has 4000 elements
i = 0
for vector in train:
    npArray[i] = vector[0]
    i += 1
```

When I try to do this I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '['
```

This is happening because after I read the file back in it is reading it as a string and not a numpy array. I've tried adding the dtype argument in the read_csv function and specifying np.array, but that gave me an error as well.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: When you write your DataFrame to a csv you lose all information about it being a numpy array and your array is just stored as a string. You can use json or you can pickle your files `df.to_pickle()` to preserve the data-types.

Comment: What does the `csv` file look like?  Normally a csv file consists of rows of text, each with a consistent number of simple columns - columns that contain text and or numbers.  How can a column that contains arrays be formatted in this way?

Comment: @ALollz I thought this was probably the issue an I've tried that, but I keep running out of memory when I try to save as a pickle, json, or parquet.

Comment: How about creating the 2d array in the original dataframe?  Saving arrays with 4000 elements in this csv string format will be inefficient, even if you can parse them.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes I've tried that, but writing a numpy 2d array with the tofile() funtion takes really long and reading it with the fromfile() funtion takes even longer that it's unreasonable.